# i can not able to get page_info using shopify Api

Tags: shopify-api

I am doing Shopify versioning in that I can not get page wise data. I review API new version in that I show page_info where to I get page_info

```
$api_url = 'https://6b4c824f22b4f24ddewwerew0a9b36397fd27e5c4:a5cb5dd808ec7392ewrewrwerwerwed8872be5aa5d3b1c@bacsolution-4.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/products.json?limit='.$limit.';rel=next';


    //$api_url = 'https://'.$shop.'/admin/products.json?limit='.$limit.'&page='.$i.'';
    //$fieldstoselect = 'id,title,variants';
    $fieldstoselect = 'id,title';
    $api_url = $api_url.'&fields='.$fieldstoselect;

    $headr = array();
    $headr[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    //$headr[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token:'.$token;
    $ch = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $response_all = json_decode($res);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response_all);
    exit;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using REST API then you will get it in the response header. have a look in below screenshot of response header.

[image]

And below post might help you on how to extract this pageInfo from response header

[How to create pagination in shopify rest api using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801924/how-to-create-pagination-in-shopify-rest-api-using-php/58412944#58412944)

Comment: Thank you for your reply it's really helpful for me.

Comment: when I get that link and  with the help of  that again do  in curl request next time I don't get link variable
here is a response

Comment: That means there is no next or previous page available for that resource. 

Please refer this answer for better understanding 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801924/how-to-create-pagination-in-shopify-rest-api-using-php/58412944#58412944